# Allignment of multiplication table in Python

Tags: python, string

I want to write a multiplication table and have the code below, the only issue is that when it prints out the code the rows and columns aren't alligned the way I want them to be. How can I make them be alligned perfectly, all in their proper position the easiest way possible so I as a beginner can understand. Thank you!

```
rows= int(input("How many rows?: "))

columns= int(input("How many columns?: "))

for row in range(1, rows+1):
   for col in range(1,columns+1):
      print(row * col, end="  ")
print()
```

Comment: instead of printing end="   ", try doing "\t" to print a tab space. Im assuming you want the numbers to all line up

Comment: for future reference, i suggest posting an expected and actual output

Comment: Do you mean like this? 
      print(row * col"\t")
If no, please show me how you mean and if yes, that doesn't print it in table form the way I want it, it prints it vertically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `str.format()` and right (or left) justify the result into 3 length (using spaces as padding) . Example -

```
for row in range(1, row+1):
    for col in range(1,columns+1):
        print("{: >3}".format(row * col), end="")
    print()
```

You can increase the length from `3` if you want to include larger number.

The format explained -

> `{: >3}` The character `:` indicates precedes the format spec (If you use string before the `:` it would be considered as a field name (which is passed in as keyword parameter to the `.format()` method or is the position of the positional argument to it) You can also add an optional conversion before `:` . This is explained in [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) .
>
> `' '` (space) after the `:` indicates what to pad with.
>
> `>` indicates right alignment
>
> `3` indicates the width in which to align.

You can find more details about the [format specification mini language here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

Demo -

```
>>> row = 5
>>> columns = 5
>>> for row in range(1, row+1):
...     for col in range(1,columns+1):
...         print("{: >3}".format(row * col), end="")
...     print()
...
  1  2  3  4  5
  2  4  6  8 10
  3  6  9 12 15
  4  8 12 16 20
  5 10 15 20 25
```

Comment: Your code works fine when I test it but when I add the "{: >3}".format to my code it doesn't display like yours, do you know why?

Comment: What is it this line {: >3} does exactly, Anand?

Comment: I have explained in the answer, do you have any questions on that?

Comment: The first `' '` (space) after `:` is the padding character (which is used to fill the extra spaces that come. Then comes the alignment `>` means right alignment . And lastly the width .

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (save it to matrix):

So the main idea the same (use **`format()`**).

```
rows = int(input("How many rows?: "))

columns = int(input("How many columns?: "))

mt = [[0 for x in range(rows)] for x in range(columns)] 

for row in range(1, rows + 1):
    for col in range(1, columns + 1):
        mt[row - 1][col - 1] = row * col

for el in mt:
    print ''.join("{: >4}".format(x) for x in el)
```